# Loop through list of lists with True/False?

Tags: python

If I have a list of lists, how can I loop through it so the return value is False if one element is false

```
a = [[True, True, True], [True, False, True]]
```

would return

```
[True, False]
```

Comment: `ret = [all(l) for l in a]`

Comment: I think efficient is `map(lambda x: not (False in x),a)`

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari if you iterate over the map object, I agree. It would also be equivalent to `map(all, a)`. But if you just convert the map return to a list using `list()`  I think my approach is a little bit more efficient.

Comment: @dalmago which map object? map is not an object here. Why do you want to convert it to list try this in shell

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `all` function.

```
[all(x) for x in a]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) as alternative of list comprehension:

```
a = [[True, True, True], [True, False, True]]
result = list(map(all, a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `all()` combined with list comprehensions.

Example:

```
return_list = [all(i) for i in my_list] # = [True, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map without list like this

```
a = [[True, True, True], [True, False, True]]
map(lambda x: not (False in x),a)
```